# VSTS: Pass build/release variables into Powershell script task

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

Ideally, I would want to configure our Azure Web App application settings using build variables (on VSTS), for example:

[image: VSTS Build]

We perform our publish tasks using Powershell scripts. In order to set app settings, the following script could be used:

```
param($websiteName, $appSettings)
Set-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName -AppSettings $appSettings
```

I could pass these build variables manually into a Powershell script build task, like so:

```
PrepareAppSettings.ps1 -websiteName "MyWebApp" -appsettings @{"MyConnectionString" = $(MyConnectionString);"MyRandomService" = $(MyRandomService);"MyRandomServiceClient"=$(MyRandomServiceClient);"MyRandomServicePassword"=$(MyRandomServicePassword)}
```

**Is there a way to pass all build variables into a script without having to explicitly specifying each one in a hash table?**

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Build Variables are automatically passed to all the PowerShell scripts as environment variables.

So if you have defined a variable `myVar` in the `Variables` section. You can access it as `$env:myVar` in your script. One thing to note here is that `.` is converted to a `_`. For eg. if your variable is `myVar.config`, you will access it in your script as `$env:myVar_config`.

The available variables also include variables such as branch name, build number etc. To see all the available variables, run a dummy build/release definition and add a PowerShell task with inline type and run `Get-ChildItem Env:`. This will show you all the available environment variables and you can see all your custom defined variables.

More details are available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/variables)

Comment: Thanks - so I ended up setting all build variables, which I intend to become App Settings, with the "App:" prefix. It certainly isn't the cleanest of approaches. `Get-ChildItem Env: | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "App:*" } | ForEach-Object { $appSettings.Add($_.Name.Substring(4), $_.Value) }`

Comment: @davenewza Yeah, it seems a good idea to put it in a dictionary if you have a lot of settings and then access them cleanly and easily.

Comment: another thing to not here is if you use hashes in your variable names (like `my-var`), you need to retrieve them by doing `(Get-Variable -Name "env:my-var").Value`

Answer (score 9):

It is worth mentioning here, that secret variables *are not passed* into scripts as environment variables (`env:` in PS). So accessible only if passed as parameters for a script, eg. `-MyPassword $(Password)`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#secret-variables

Answer (score 3):

The variables have already been passed to PowerShell script when the build start. If I understand your question correctly, you want to use these variables together instead of specifying them one by one like following:

```
PrepareAppSettings.ps1 -websiteName "MyWebApp" -appsettings $(AllVariables)
```

Then there isn't any way to do this.

If you want to reduce the strings passed to the PowerShell script, you can set the variable as following:

> VariableName: MyRandomService | Value:"MyRandomService" = xxxxxxxx

Then you just need to call the PowerShell script with variable name passed.

Answer (score 0):

You could have also used **variable groups** to achieve this, thus maintaining variables that are closely related, isolated from the build variables and from other groups of related variables. I have shown how to easily set this up in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61313916/1198379).