# Read a user input while queue a VSTS Build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I want to pass few arguments to the VSTS build tasks while queue a build (The same way we do for Jenkins). How can i do that.
I want to read a comma seperated string and want to pass that argument to a Windows Batch Script task in VSTS build job. 
I am new to VSTS, someone please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997494/vsts-pass-build-variables-into-powershell-script-task

Answer (score 2):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Add a variable in build definition
2. Check Settable at queue time option

[image]

3. Specify that variable in Batch Script task

[image]

Comment: Solved my issue...Thanks a lot

Comment: I have one more question here.. Can i add drop down variables like Jenkins?

Comment: No, drop down variable is not supported in VSTS.

Comment: so what is the alternative ?

Comment: There isn't the alternative way, you can submit the user voice here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services?category_id=145254

Answer (score 0):

On the Variables tab, add a variable and check the "Settable at queue time" box. The variable will then appear in the queue build dialog, and will appear as an environment variable in your script.

Comment: I have one more question here.. Can i add drop down variables like Jenkins?